# How to get checkbox value from inside an HTML table using JS

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm currently working on a simple website where I have a list of PC parts in a table. In this table I also have checkboxes which are meant to be checked if the parts are owned. At the bottom of a table is a button which will be pressed that is meant to check the status of the checkboxes and output the list of parts still needed and the approximate cost.

I'm having issues with accessing the checked state of the checkboxes through Javascript and keep getting undefined when I try to output the value in the console.

Site Table Image:

[image]

HTML Code:

```html
 <div class="beginnersguide">
            <h1>What parts go into a gaming PC?</h1>

            <table id="partsTable">
                <tr>
                    <th onclick="sortTable(0)" id="partName">Part Name</th>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th onclick="sortTable(3, 1)" id="averagePrice">Average Price ($CAD)</th>
                    <th>Already Owned?</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Case</td>
                    <td><img src="../img/case.jpg"></td>
                    <td>The nicely designed box/container for all your PC parts. This is what you will first see when looking at your PC!</td>
                    <td>150</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Motherboard</td>
                    <td><img src="../img/motherboard.jpg"></td>
                    <td>The Motherboard is a large circuit board which acts as the central hub for all your internal PC components. It will connect all the parts inside together to run!</td>
                    <td>210</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                
                // Code continues on like this for the rest of the table and ends like this:
                
               <tr>
                    <td>Input and Output Devices</td>
                    <td><img src="../img/iodevice.jpg"></td>
                    <td>This would cover items such as a mouse, keyboard and monitors. These are needed to interact with your PC.</td>   
                    <td>250</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" name="check" value="Check List" onclick="checkList()">
```

JavaScript Code:

```js
/* Function for Parts checklist */
function checkList(){
    var table, rows = 0;
    table = document.getElementById("partsTable");
    rows = table.rows;

    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[4];
      //console.log(x);
      if (x.checked == true){
        /* code to output what parts are necessary */
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be worth trying to grab the child by its tag `input` rather than relying on it being the 5th `td` in the row.

Comment: I tried using "getElementsByTagName("INPUT") but I am unable to check this afterwards by doing x.checked == true, or atleast its not actually checking the value of the checkbox

Comment: nvm I was able to get it to work now! I continued with this line "getElementsByTagName("INPUT")" but added "[0]" to the end of it after checking what the HTMLCollection structure was in the console. Thank you for the help!